# Reading multiple data files in awk using a wildcard

Tags: awk

I have several data files named file1.dat, file2.dat etc each containing two columns and three lines.

I read the multiple files by using the command

```
awk '{print $2}' file*.dat
```

This nicely lists as output the second column in all files. However, when I try to read
only the second line in each file, only the first file file1.dat is read.

```
awk '{if(NR==2) print $2}' file*.dat
```

The problem persists even when I type

```
awk '{if(NR==2) print $2}' file1.dat file2.dat file3.dat
```

i.e. when I omit the wildcard

obviously my syntax is terribly wrong. I am using awk (not gawk) on MacOS Mojave if this matters. I would be very interested to know what I have done wrong.

Comment: try `FNR` in place of `NR`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting then [edit] your question to provide and format sample input, expected output and code as Code Blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `FNR` rather than `NR` is the key here.  `NR` is the overall record number for all provided input; `FNR` is the record number for the current input file being processed.

So:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}' ./file*.dat
```

Also note the `condition {action}` pattern which is more idiomatic in `awk` rather omitting the *condition* and having `if()` in the *action* part.

Also note the `./` prefix which you generally want to use when using globs with `awk` to avoid problems when file names may contain `=` characters.

Also beware that globs are sorted lexically, `./file1.dat`, `./file10.dat`, `./file11.dat`, `./file2.data`, `./file3.data`... are sorted in that order. With the `zsh` shell, you can use `./file*.dat(n)` to get them in `./file1.dat`, `./file2.data`, `./file3.data`... `./file10.dat`, `./file11.dat` order.